# URL not working in function (WMS)

Tags: openlayers, wms

I am working with a function that should display one image of roads, and OpenStreetMaps as background, with some functionality. But I can't figure out why my code isn't working - the URL works fine but when opening the HTML file it does not display any of the maps. The function (sorry for the indentation that got messed up when pasting):

```
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
function init(){
    //The bounding box of wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads
    var extent = [-74.00083695216,40.7366919238975,-73.97236135813849,40.769490143183006],
    ol.proj.transformExtent(-74.00083695216,40.7366919238975,-73.97236135813849,40.769490143183006, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');  

    //Initial view
    var view = new ol.View({
       center: ol.proj.transform([-73.99, 40.75], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
       zoom: 15
    });

    //The source for wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads
    var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
         url: 'http://flygbilder.gis.lu.se/geoserver/wsNYCRoads/wms',
         params: {
         'LAYERS': 'wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads',
         'VERSION': '1.1.0'},
          serverType: 'geoserver'
        });

    //OpenStreetMap background and wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads in layers
    var layers = [
       new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
       }),
       new ol.layer.Image({
          source: wmsSource
       })
     ];
    //Bind the map object to our "map" div and add some extra functionality
    var map = new ol.Map({
         layers: layers,
         controls: ol.control.defaults({
         attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
         collapsible: false
       })
       }).extend([

     //Extra functionality of the map
     //Control for displaying coordinates

       new ol.control.MousePosition({
           coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
           projection: 'EPSG:4326',
           className: 'custom-mouse-position',
           target: document.getElementById('location'),
           undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
         }),

      //COntrol for displaying a scale line
       new ol.control.ScaleLine({
       target: document.getElementById('scale-line')
       }),

      //Control for zoming to a defined extent
      new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
      extent: ol.proj.transform(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
    })
    ]),
       target: 'map',
       view: view
    });

    //Add click event for getting attributes from WMS
    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
     document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
     evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
     {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
     if (url) {
        document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe
            style="width:950px;border:none;" src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
   });
}
```

GetCapabilities for layer nyc_road:

```
 </Layer>
 <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
    <Name>nyc_roads</Name>
    <Title>nyc_roads</Title>
    <Abstract>Hello</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>
      <Keyword>nyc_roads</Keyword>
      <Keyword>features</Keyword>
    </KeywordList>
    <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>

    <!--WKT definition of this CRS:
    GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]-->

    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-74.00083695216647" miny="40.7366919238975" maxx="-73.97236135813849" maxy="40.769490143183006"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-74.00083695216647" miny="40.7366919238975" maxx="-73.97236135813849" maxy="40.769490143183006"/>
```

Comment: Did you verify that the CRS transforms are fine? And that you're centered on the right coordinates (try zooming out)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There should not be a problem with the CRS transform or the coordinates, these were pre-written (not by me). The OpenStreeMap is in EPSG:3857, and the layer "wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads is in EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you add OpenStreetMap to your map you set the projection to epsg:3857 (Web Mercator), but you are forcing the request to GeoServer to be in epsg:4326 because you have hardcoded that value into the SRS parameter. So GeoServer (being a trusting program) returns that image which will appear as a very small black spot near where the equator crosses the prime meridian (Null Island) when openlayers interprets the degrees as meters.

**TLDR;** remove the SRS line from your WMSSource.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But it did no difference, still not getting my layer or OpenStreetMap showing.

Comment: your extent is in 4326 too so you will need to zoom out (a lot) to see anything

Comment: Do you mean "var extent = [-74.00083695216,40.7366919238975,-73.97236135813849,40.769490143183006];"?, shouldn't that be handled by "center: ol.proj.transform([-73.99, 40.75], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')"?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to transform the extent too

Comment: I appreciate your fast answers! I tried to transform the extent without any luck (see edit). But since the layer works fine as a standalone in the browser (full url: http://flygbilder.gis.lu.se/geoserver/wsNYCRoads/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=wsNYCRoads:nyc_roads&styles=&bbox=-74.00083695216647,40.7366919238975,-73.97236135813849,40.769490143183006&width=444&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fjpeg) I really think your on to the problem, something must be wrong with the SRS. It is getting really frustrating.

Comment: next most likely problem is that you have swapped axis order try 40.74592015984784155,-73.99570567896094531,40.75452969241028711,-73.97525803912512288 for the bbox

Comment: Hmm, the extent should be fine according to getcapabilities (http://flygbilder.gis.lu.se/geoserver/wsNYCRoads/wms?request=getCapabilities). Also tried to swap without any luck.